# How to use Google relyingparty to disable user Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to disable Firebase users from my app but the Firebase documentation only give me the option to delete users.

I think the solution is like create users ex:
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[YourKey]

but there is no documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK has an option to disable users.

See [this the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), which contains this code sample:

> ```
> admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
>   email: "modifiedUser@example.com",
>   emailVerified: true,
>   password: "newPassword",
>   displayName: "Jane Doe",
>   photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
>   disabled: true
> })
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log("Error updating user:", error);
>   });
> ```